How to Disable One Signal Notification in Android
I have a notification button in my app and I want to enable and disable notification when user clicks on that button. I am able to get the notification enabled with permission but don't know how to disable it.
onClick = {
                    Notifications = !Notifications
                    scope.launch {
                        dataStore.saveNotificationState(Notifications)
                    }
                    if (Notifications) {
                        greetingUser("Notification Turned on.", context)
                        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                            OneSignal.Notifications.requestPermission(true)
//                          OneSignal.User.pushSubscription.optIn() Not needed.
//                          Enable works Fine
                        }
                    } else {
                        greetingUser("Notification Turned off.", context)
//                        OneSignal.User.pushSubscription.optOut() Not working.
//                      OneSignal.disablePush() Not found in latest Sdk.

                    }

                }


Gradle

implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[5.0.0, 5.99.99]'


I have tried several solutions but none of them working. I am not able to disable the notification from One Signal. Once user approves the notification the notification will keep coming.
Thanks in advance.
